# SQLITE for each row of a table, count occurences in two others tables

Tags: sqlite

I need some help to simplify the below request and also make it faster to execute. Here is what I'm trying to do :

Table Player (idPlayer, namePlayer) 
*Contains the list of players*

Table EventPVE (idPlayer)
*Each line represents an event when a player got killed by the game environment*

Table EventPVP (idPlayerKilled, idPlayerKiller)
*each line represents an event when a player kills or get killed by another player*

I'm trying, for each player, to count how many time they got killed by the environment, how many time they got killed by a player and how many time they killed another player. The request below works but is very slow (3 subrequests of course)

Could you please help me to simplify it ? I'm very bad at sql .... I've seen some "solutions" with LEFT JOIN but it seems that it doesn't work in my case. The first LEFT JOIN works well but the others return bad counts.

```
SELECT  p.idPlayer, p.namePlayer,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*) 
        FROM    EventPVE pve
        WHERE   pve.idPlayer = p.idPlayer
        ) AS pveDeath,
         (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    EventPVP pvp
        WHERE   pvp.idPlayerKiller = p.idPlayer
        ) AS pvpKills,
         (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    EventPVP pvp
        WHERE   pvp.idPlayerKilled = p.idPlayer
        ) AS pvpDeaths
FROM    Player p
```

Here is a test db : https://www.dropbox.com/s/tc7z1i26mumvhgm/test.db?dl=0

Comment: Do `Player` and `EventPVE` each have at least one index defined in which the leftmost column is `idPlayer`; and does `EventPVP` have at least one such index for each of `idPlayerKiller` and `idPlayerKilled`?

Comment: No, there is no primary key or index in any of EventPVE or EventPVP. Though, Player has idPlayer as Primary key. There is no duplicated row in the Player table

Comment: If it helps I can share the database. It's a SQLITE one.

Comment: If it's SQLite, why have you tagged this question [tag:mysql] and not [tag:sqlite]??!

Comment: Here is a link to the test database : https://www.dropbox.com/s/tc7z1i26mumvhgm/test.db?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

The query itself already is as simple as possible.

The problem is that the database has to scan all the tables to find rows with matching player ID values, and it has to do this once for every player.

These lookups could be sped up with some indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ep ON EventPVE(idPlayer);
CREATE INDEX pkiller ON EventPVP(idPlayerKiller);
CREATE INDEX pkilled ON EventPVP(idPlayerKilled);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there's no need of second Table `EventPVE`.

Try this:
SELECT *FROM eventpvp left join player on eventpvp.idPlayerKilled=player.idPlayer group by idPlayerKilled

[image]

It is working for me. I didn't used the database you provided, i created one.

Comment: I'm not an expert at SQLITE but how could this work without even a "count" in the request so that I'm trying to display 3 counters :p The return of the query must be like : idPlayer | namePlayer | pveDeathCount | pvpDeathsCount | pvpKillsCount

Comment: @vfloyd please check the attached image

Comment: what do you mean by 3 counters i didn't get it. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Ok, basically I want to count how many time each player is pointed in the table EventPVE by the field idPlayer, how many time each players is pointed in the table EventPVP by the field idPlayerKilled, how many time each player is pointed in the table EventPVP by the field  idPlayerKiller.